# Extracting Json Data from PHP log file

Tags: php, json, parsing, csv

I am newbie to php,
Here is my json file ,

```
{"hint_data":{"locations":["AXQDAP____8AAAAABwAAABEAAAAYAAAAIwIAAERwAgAAAAAADgyCAef7TAMCAAEB","bOsDAP____8AAAAAAwAAAAcAAADFAQAAFAAAAEJwAgAAAAAANQeCAdzdTAMFAAEB"],"checksum":326195011},"route_name":["",""],"via_indices":[0,15],"via_points":[[25.299982,55.376873],[25.29874,55.369179]],"found_alternative":false,"route_summary":{"end_point":"","start_point":"","total_time":101,"total_distance":871},"route_geometry":"{_ego@m}|rhBpBaBvHuC`EuArEUtEtAlDvEnD`MlDvMli@hsEfFzn@QlTgNhwCs@fKwBjF","status_message":"Found route between points","status":0}
```

I need to extract the **total_time** only from the json and print it to a csv file,could someone please help me in that?

Comment: using `json_decode` and foreach loop

Comment: Could you please write a full code? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `json_decode` you can get the total time from your json.

Using the `json_decode` you can get the associative array and using the indices you can access the value of total time as shown below.

[Check online](https://3v4l.org/qiFnq)

```
$json = '{"hint_data":{"locations":["AXQDAP____8AAAAABwAAABEAAAAYAAAAIwIAAERwAgAAAAAADgyCAef7TAMCAAEB","bOsDAP____8AAAAAAwAAAAcAAADFAQAAFAAAAEJwAgAAAAAANQeCAdzdTAMFAAEB"],"checksum":326195011},"route_name":["",""],"via_indices":[0,15],"via_points":[[25.299982,55.376873],[25.29874,55.369179]],"found_alternative":false,"route_summary":{"end_point":"","start_point":"","total_time":101,"total_distance":871},"route_geometry":"{_ego@m}|rhBpBaBvHuC`EuArEUtEtAlDvEnD`MlDvMli@hsEfFzn@QlTgNhwCs@fKwBjF","status_message":"Found route between points","status":0}';
$assoc = true;
$result = json_decode ($json, $assoc);

echo $result['route_summary']['total_time']; //101
```

Comment: Thanks frayne i'll cheeck that out. and what if there are around 900 json data,should i store that on a file and parse that file?

Comment: Check here: https://3v4l.org/qiFnq

Comment: you need to track on the array that is achieved from `json_decode`. If you can see that than there are no confusion like you think.

Comment: Use your json sting [here](http://php.fnlist.com/php/json_decode) and see the array.

Comment: Thanks,and Frayne, if i need to add a column to my file title "total_time" following the total time data extracted from json what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

First, You decode the JSON Data back into PHP Object. Then you you can access the Total Time Property of the Object as shown below:

```
    <?php
        $json       = '{"hint_data":{"locations":["AXQDAP____8AAAAABwAAABEAAAAYAAAAIwIAAERwAgAAAAAADgyCAef7TAMCAAEB","bOsDAP____8AAAAAAwAAAAcAAADFAQAAFAAAAEJwAgAAAAAANQeCAdzdTAMFAAEB"],"checksum":326195011},"route_name":["",""],"via_indices":[0,15],"via_points":[[25.299982,55.376873],[25.29874,55.369179]],"found_alternative":false,"route_summary":{"end_point":"","start_point":"","total_time":101,"total_distance":871},"route_geometry":"{_ego@m}|rhBpBaBvHuC`EuArEUtEtAlDvEnD`MlDvMli@hsEfFzn@QlTgNhwCs@fKwBjF","status_message":"Found route between points","status":0}';
        $data       = json_decode($json);
        $totalTime  = $data->route_summary->total_time;
        var_dump($totalTime);    // DUMPS     101
```